# eclipse c/c++ not compiling source code in sub folders

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

Using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (see details below)
I try to reorganize my code in sub folders. However, if I move a source code file from the existing sub folder to a new sub folder, it is not being compiled. 
I added the new sub folder to Paths and Symbols->Source locations (and Include) , and it didn't help.
My project is based on the Hello_world example from  https://github.com/CHERTS/esp8266-devkit.git and it compiles perfectly with it's own sub folder (user) but not with mine :-(

Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800
Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools
Version: 8.5.0.201409172108

Comment: Show the "project explorer" with your project expanded together with you "source locations" as screenshots (but only the relevant parts, please with reasonable resolution and size).

Answer (score 1):

If you open the `makefile` you'll finde the lines:

```
# which modules (subdirectories) of the project to include in compiling
MODULES = driver user
```

It looks like you can just add your sub-folders there.

Comment: Yes ! It works. Note that you have to add every sub folder that you wants to include: For example, if your source structure is mainfolder/mymodule/subfolder and you have source code in all folders and subfolders then your MODULES wil looks like: MODULES = mainfolder mainfolder/mymodule mainfolder/mymodule/subfolder

Comment: @itti if you ever log in again, rather than just ask one question, get an answer & never come back, then please 1) upvote this, and 2) accept it as the answer. Doing so will help others in future, ***just like you were helped***